# How to create a dict with functions from a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class like this:

```py
class example:
    def func1:
        print('bla bla')

    def func2:
        print('bla bla 2')
```

Now I want a dict with all the functions in the class like so:

```py
{'func1': <function example.func1 at 0xBLABLA>,
'func2': <function example.func2 at 0xBLABLA2>}
```

I think that are pointers but I don't know.

And I don't want to create the dict manually. It should be created automatically.

So how can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at `example.__dict__`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How do I get list of methods in a Python class?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1911281)

Comment: This could have been easily picked up from the thread that @Aran-Fey posted; please do search before asking; it helps keep a clean knowledge base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do, filtering only callables form the class `__dict__`:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in Example.__dict__.items() if callable(v)}
{'foo1': <function Example.foo1 at 0x7fe2ce405840>, 'foo2': <function Example.foo2 at 0x7fe2cb304ea0>}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thank you!

Comment: This won't return any methods decorated with `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`, and also not any methods defined in parent classes.

Comment: But it's ok me. If not I would simply remove all the methods with '__' in the dict and don't remove them if they aren't callable.

Comment: As @Aran-Fey suggested; if you're looking for getting everything needed; you'll need to use `dir()` or `inspect`.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, class names start with a uppercase; whilst the functions need to have the `self` argument or mark them as `static` which would still require you to add parenthesis as shown below.

```
class Example:
    def func1(self):
        print('bla bla')

    def func2(self):
        print('bla bla 2')
```

**Manual - Addition to achieve what you want:**

```
my_functions = {
    Example.func1,
    Example.func2
}

print(my_functions)
```

**Output:**

```
{<function example.func2 at 0x7fc5f160e620>, <function example.func1 at 0x7fc5f160e6a8>}
```

**Automatic - Addition to achieve what you want:**

```
functions = {}
for name, value in Example.__dict__.items():
    if callable(value):
        functions[name] = value

print(functions)
```

**Output:**

```
{'func1': <function Example.func1 at 0x7f58c24c26a8>, 'func2': <function Example.func2 at 0x7f58c24c2620>}
```